# Extract string using SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, sql-server-2012, substring

I have a string in the form of

```
<div>#FIRST#12345#</div>
```

How do I extract the number part from this string using T-SQL in SQL Server 2012? Note the number has variable length

Comment: Could you have a value like `<div>#FIRST#12345#SECOND#98765#</div>`? Is the value always in a `div` tag? Is the tag always valid XML? Is it stored as `xml`? Multiple examples are key here.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: If your data is consistently wrapped in # symbols you can easily extract with existing t-sql string functions. Is it?

Comment: @Larnu Yes the data is always wrapped in the DIV. This is data entered by a user but it "should" always be in the format DIV#FIRST#<some number>#DIV. All I'm trying to do is extract the number for later use

Comment: @Stu I'm not sure if I can run T-SQL on MS SQL 2012. I might be wrong though...

Comment: *"I'm not sure if I can run T-SQL on MS SQL 2012* T-SQL is the SQL dialect SQL Server uses, @Bugz ...

Comment: I found this as a possible answer but I don't like the fact that it's ordering: SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT('<div>#FIRST#12345#</div>', '#') ORDER BY 1 OFFSET 2 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY

Comment: @Bugz you're using SQL Server 2012; you can't use `STRING_SPLIT`.

Comment: @Larnu Oh damn... Any other ideas?

Comment: You say the string "should" be in that format. Validate that during ingestion? Or, how do you want this to behave if the string format does Not conform to your happy-path expectations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using just t-sql string functions you can try:

```
create table t(col varchar(50))
insert into t select '<div>#FIRST#12345#</div>'
insert into t select '<div>#THIRD#543#</div>'
insert into t select '<div>#SECOND#3690123#</div>'

select col, 
  case when p1.v=0 or p2.v <= p1.v then '' 
    else Substring(col, p1.v, p2.v-p1.v) 
  end ExtractedNumber
from t
cross apply(values(CharIndex('#',col,7) + 1))p1(v)
cross apply(values(CharIndex('#',col, p1.v + 1)))p2(v)
```

Output:

[image]

Caveat, this doesn't handle any "edge" cases and assumes data is as described.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you explain what the p1(V) & p2(v) does?

Comment: Yes, p1 and p2 are the requires *aliases* for the cross apply (so the *select* can reference them) and v is the column alias for the query returned in the cross apply; in this case it's for the single column of the *value* clause - if there were 2 columns then you'd need two aliases eg (v,x)

Answer (score 2):

Shooting from the hip due to a missing **minimal reproducible example**.

Assuming that it is XML data type column.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, xmldata XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl (xmldata) VALUES
('<div>#FIRST#12345#</div>'),
('<div>#FIRST#770770#</div>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT t.*
    , LEFT(x, CHARINDEX('#', x) - 1) AS Result
FROM @tbl t
    CROSS APPLY xmldata.nodes('/div/text()') AS t1(c)
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT REPLACE(c.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)'), '#FIRST#' ,'')) AS t2(x);
```

**Output**

```
+----+---------------------------+--------+
| ID |          xmldata          | Result |
+----+---------------------------+--------+
|  1 | <div>#FIRST#12345#</div>  |  12345 |
|  2 | <div>#FIRST#770770#</div> | 770770 |
+----+---------------------------+--------+
```

Comment: Could do with a case expression or something to prevent an error if the string doesn't conform to expectations.  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e6a2b721ae0e53318eda8003cdd736ea

Comment: @MatBailie, the OP is not providing a minimal reproducible example. So we really don't know anything about real data, its data type, etc. So it is not worthy to polish the answer yet.

Comment: Lazy questions deserve lazy answers? Mmmkay...

Comment: Sorry for the short quest. The question was more around string manipulation operations in general. Next time I'll be sure to add more info